# Find and replace variable text in Textwrangler

Tags: replace, find, textwrangler

I am looking for a way to replace variable text in large text file in TextWrangler.

Here is an example of text that I am starting with:

```
144:           FTLF8529P3BCV-CS  
22492:         TRS2200SN-000C  
24524:         SFBR-5780APZ-CS2  
26538:         FTLF1428P2BNV-CS  
30916:         TRS7250SN-S103
```

And I want to replace it into following:

```
FTLF8529P3BCV-CS  
TRS2200SN-000C  
SFBR-5780APZ-CS2  
FTLF1428P2BNV-CS  
TRS7250SN-S103
```

Is there a find and replace option that will allow me to do this?

I tried inbuilt grep function, but it does not seem to be working correctly for me. The original text that I am trying to modify is slightly different then above.

It looks like this:

untitled text 16:144:Vendor PN          FTLF8529P3BCV-CS
untitled text 16:22492: Vendor PN        TRS2200SN-000C
untitled text 16:24524: Vendor PN        SFBR-5780APZ-CS2
untitled text 16:26538: Vendor PN        FTLF1428P2BNV-CS
untitled text 16:30916: Vendor PN        TRS7250SN-S103

So I tried grep find on "untitled text 16**Vendor PN          " but that did not work. I got syntax error.

Here is the full error message:

The search cannot proceed, because of a syntax error in the Grep pattern: nothing to repeat (application error code: 12209).

I tried this, and it works:

```
untitled text 16:[0-9]*: Vendor PN [ ]*\
```

Thanks!

Comment: please share what you have done so far to try and resolve this problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have marked up your text data by adding 4 spaces to it.  This has the side-effect of preserving your spaces so that it looks aligned.  Please edit you post and list anything you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Go to text wrangler and under the search tab, choose Multi File Search.  You will notice that a checkbox called Grep is probably checked.  Uncheck that box and it should work.